# How to webscrape a title?

Tags: python, html, title

I was wondering how to webscrape the title of the first video in an youtube-playlist ?

what I have so far try'd:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lp-EO5I60KA&list=PLMC9KNkIncKtPzgY-5rmhvj7fax8fdxoj"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")

print(soup.findAll("h1",{"class":"title style-scope ytd-video-primary-info-renderer"}))
```

But it only prints = "[]" as output. Am I doing something wrong here ?

greetings

Comment: 1. you can use YouTube API instead; 2. you can look for the `<title>` tag instead.

Comment: @Raptor sorry, but im new to python and just started 20 min ago looking at html in total completly new to programming. How would the code look with the "<title> tag ? I didnt see such kind of tag. thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Title tag is in the HTML `<head>`, which contains the title of the video in YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

```
all = (soup.findAll("span",{"class":"title"}))
for a in all:
    print(a.text)
    break
```

When I looked in the soup, I could see the **playlist** has `class=title` for each song in the list. The output is:

```
Ed Sheeran - Thinking Out Loud [Official Video]
```

Comment: Thank you! With your code as a blueprint il be able to understand whats happening waaay faster :D