# Is there a better way to webscrape MSFT data in shorter lines? I have tried it already but get the issue 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, stock-data

[tried following the same method, didnt work out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47502849/how-to-webscrape-a-title)

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

#data I want to pull then push a while loop to get it regularly by the minute
r = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT?p=MSFT&.tsrc=fin-srch') 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'xml')
print(soup)
```

Comment: There are at least three distinct questions in here, none of which are up to par. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No Module Named bs4 (BeautifulSoup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783875/importerror-no-module-named-bs4-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

You need to call a function of soup object. For example:

```
print(soup.get_text())
```